# extract the max value from string in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I work with PostgreSQL and I want to extract the max value with this query:

```
select max (num_ordre_decision) from decision
```

The problem is that `num_ordre_decision` contains this kind of data:

```
'4/35/677'
'4/35/1001'
```

The type of my column is **String**. When I run this query I have the max value:

```
'4/35/1001'
```

which is **false**.

I want just to compare `677` with `1001` in order to have the max value `'4/35/677'` in the previous case.

I think that I should use **split** in my query.

#### Update

I tried with this query:

```
select max(split_part(num_ordre_decision, '/', 3))
from decision;
```

I have this value: `'99'`

When I try to run this query

```
select split_part(num_ordre_decision, '/', 3)
from decision;
```

I get this result

```
''
''
'677'
'1001'
'99'
```

This result `''` appears because the real value in the table does not contain the separator `'/'`. I think that `max(split_part(num_ordre_decision, '/', 3)`  makes the sum meaning it makes `9+9`. But the correct result should be `1001`

So they must be compared as numbers.

**Updated :**

I want to use this query in my project

I have this function :

```
 public List getMaxNumOrder (){
        
        String query= "select max(NULLIF(split_part(num_ordre_decision, '/', 3), '')::int) from decision";
        
        SQLQuery sqlQuery = this.getSession().createSQLQuery(query);
    
         return sqlQuery.list();
    
    }
```

but when I have this error :

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set: [:int] [select max(NULLIF(split_part(num_ordre_decision, '/', 3), '')::int) from decision]
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.verifyParameters(AbstractQueryImpl.java:339)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.verifyParameters(SQLQueryImpl.java:228)
```

I think that I should use : **query.setParameter**

I do not know how to use it

Comment: what did you try so far with split?

Comment: `select max (num_ordre_decision) from decision` does return `4/35/677`, see [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1a25e/3/0)

Comment: In the top of your question, you say that you want the answer to be `667`, but in the lower updated portion, you say you want `1001`.  The max between 667 and 1001 is 1001.  So my answer reflects that, but you should clarify your question.

Comment: `max(split_part(num_ordre_decision, '/', 3)` does NOT make a SUM value.  It splits the string, gets the 3rd value, then finds the max value for that column.

Comment: "string" is not a data type and values are quoted with *single* quotes in Postgres. I fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the max *value* as:

```
select max(split_part(num_ordre_decision, '/', 3))
from decision;
```

To get the overall max, you might want:

```
select num_ordre_decision
from decision
order by split_part(num_ordre_decision, '/', 3) desc
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Continuing @Gordon's fine work.  If you want to sort the last section by integer, you need to cast the value as such.

This will also handle your empty strings.

```
select 
  max(NULLIF(split_part(num_ordre_decision, '/', 3), '')::int)
from decision;
```

### [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/60d46/1)

Comment: thank you , it works when I run it in database, but I have problem when I use it in my project

Comment: I make sqlQuery.setParameter(":int", );  but I didn't know what I should make in the second parameter

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative approach (when you need the max value over all columns):

select max(some_val) from (select 
  UNNEST(string_to_array(num_ordre_decision, '/'))::int as some_val
from decision)x;